# What are 'true' and 'false' and 'null'?

Tags: javascript, keyword

Why aren't they keywords? What are they?

```
true, false, null
```

**Update Quick Answer**

These are reserved words but they are not keywords.

Small technical distinction verified by spec - ES3 and ES5

Comment: What makes you say they aren't reserved words? `true = 6` will never work, that kind of makes it a reserved word.

Comment: sorry...they are not keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `true` and `false` are reserved words in Javascript, from:

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1

```
A reserved word is an IdentifierName that cannot be used as an Identifier.

Syntax
    ReservedWord ::
        Keyword
        FutureReservedWord
        NullLiteral
        BooleanLiteral
```

and in

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.2

you can read:

```
Boolean Literals

Syntax
    BooleanLiteral ::
        true
        false
```

Comment: you forgot: browser implementation lies

Comment: ECMA-262 is the standard.  If it's lying, you're simply screwed.

Comment: I think I'm going to just read the spec from here, and make my own interpretation.

Answer (score 11):

They are *boolean literals*. From the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> ```
> BooleanLiteral ::
>    true
>    false
> ```
>
> - The value of the Boolean literal `true` is a value of the Boolean type, namely `true`.
> - The value of the Boolean literal `false` is a value of the Boolean type, namely `false`.

It is similar to how `10` is a *numeric literal* or `'foo'` is a *string literal*.

*Reserved words* includes keywords and literals. The words  `true` and `false` are *reserved words*, but they are not *keywords*. The following are *keywords*:

```
break    do       instanceof typeof
case     else     new        var
catch    finally  return     void
continue for      switch     while
debugger function this       with
default  if       throw
delete   in       try
```

Notice that `true` and `false` don't appear in this list.

I think your confusion comes from not realising that the two terms *keyword* and *reserved word* are not the same. Every keyword is a reserved word, but not every reserved word is a keyword.

Comment: @Hiro, that's unfortunate. That said, you can rest assured Javascript implementors stick to the spec, not to The Good Parts, as enlightening as they might be.

Answer (score 4):

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

> Additionally, the literals null, true, and false are reserved in
>   ECMAScript for their normal uses.

They actually do appear to be "reserved" for usage, but I have no clue why they are not listed as a reserved word.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure why it's not listed ON the reserved word list I was simply linking to the text that states they are reserved for their literal usage.

Comment: They're not listed because they're not quite keywords; they're just values with special names.  Note that `undefined` and `null` aren't in MDN's list either.

Comment: @Hiro: Thing is, should 42 be on the list as well?  Numbers are literals too, and have just as valid a case.  The fact that some literals are spelled with letters rather than digits doesn't change that they're literals, and not keywords.

Comment: I don't define what a "reserved word", is ES5 does.  There are two different concepts you don't want to confuse...a keyword and a reserved word...pqnet has links to where in ES5 this is defined.

Comment: @Hiro: I have a copy of ECMA-262 (it's available for free as a PDF), so i can easily look up stuff like this whenever i need to :)

Comment: well I'm going to start reading it...seems like most JavaScript books each give a different interpretation of it...why no just go right to the source...and save yourself from confusion...

Comment: @Jared...your reputation keeps changing...now it has 825? I don't think that is correct.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist what? rep goes up/down as you use the site :)

Answer (score 1):

With non object javascript you just write

```
if( sami.value = true) //Noticed i didn't put ==
```

if it is object 
The Boolean object represents two values: "true" or "false".

The following code creates a Boolean object called myBoolean:

```
var myBoolean=new Boolean();
```

If the Boolean object has no initial value, or if the passed value is one of the following:

```
0
-0
null
""
false
undefined
NaN
```

the object is set to false. For any other value it is set to true (even with the string "false")!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: You should also format your answers properly by marking code as code/etc this way they are easily read by all.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know i am really knew here :P